# LinkedIn API method

Tags: php, linkedin-api

Hello and I hope someone can assist me with this problem since LinkedIn don't have the answer themselves.  I am trying to post to a group using the php Class LinkedInV2.  I can certainly do it using the LinkedIn
test group, so the syntax is correct.   However, for a real group with real admin users, I would need a method to authenticate the user.  Such a method does not appear to exist as far as I can tell and LinkedIn cannot help me. As a result, I get validation error
stdClass Object ( [message] => com.linkedin.content.common.ResponseException: denied by [resource: organizationUgcAuthorizations => responseStatus: DENIED] [status] => 403 )

If anyone has information on this, or guidelines as to how to create such a method, I am sure a lot of people would be eternally grateful.

Comment: This appears relevant to your problem: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/guide/v2/concepts/authentication

Comment: Thank you although I believe that the application is correctly authenticated and is getting a correct Access Token..  I understand that the problem lies in authenticating the user against the group to ensure that the user has permission to post to it.